# How to pass String value along with web service when getting list view data from web service

Tags: android, json, listview, arraylist

Here is my code to Get list view data from web service , my code is working fine and displaying the list of images list view. But i want to pass string customer_id along with web service call , What i want is web service data should be obtained in my device only when  am passing the customer_id to the web service url , like registration procedure. But here i dont know how to pass string value , am strct with this please help me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String RANK = "rank";
static String COUNTRY = "country";
static String POPULATION = "population";
static String FLAG = "flag";
TextView userid;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    userid=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.customerid);
    userid.setText("10");
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}
//  private void feedback() {
//      String customer_id = userid.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
//      list(customer_id);
//  }

//  private void list(String customer_id) {
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://sridharweb2.esy.es/gift_voucher.php" );

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("gift_voucher");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                //  map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("gift_voucher_name"));
                map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("gift_voucher_price"));
                map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("gift_voucher_image"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void execute(String customer_id) {
    }
}
//      DownloadJSON ru = new DownloadJSON();
//      ru.execute(customer_id);
//  }
}
```

Comment: its simple send customer id with url like this  http://sridharweb2.esy.es/gift_voucher.php?customer_id="cisd"

Comment: Use a library like retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: you can pass as parameter to your webservice. Change your webservice to REST and make a GET method with id

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Customer Id to the URL and execute the webservice like this --

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

URL url = new URL("http://sridharweb2.esy.es/gift_voucher.php");

  connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  connection.setUseCaches(false);
  connection.setConnectTimeout(720000000);
  connection.setReadTimeout(72000000);
  connection.connect();

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("customer_id", customer_id)
String data = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
     output.write(data);
     output.flush();
     output.close();

connection.disconnect();
```

In this you are basically appending all the input data and forming the query.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi saumik can u tell me how can i include it in my code

Comment: @SivakumarS -- I have edited my answer to provide you the entire implementation. Please check that. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: ,Thanks ill implement it